# Problem with empty password. Async function

Tags: express, bcrypt

Hello i have a problem with adding user to database. The problem is when i try to hash password, there's an error that says the password is empty. If i send req.body.password it works. Problem appears only with const hashed_password

Here's my code

```
const addUser = async (req, res) => {


const { email, password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen } = req.body;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashed_password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  try {

//checking for duplicated phone or email
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
const phoneNumber = await User.findOne({ telephone });

if (user) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User email already exists' });
}
else if (phoneNumber) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: "Phone number already exists" })
}
console.log(hashed_password);
const result = await User.create({
  email, hashed_password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen
});

res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created', user: result });



 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Error message:
password: ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a object, and it requires a password.

Please edit as follows

```
const result = await User.create({
  email, password: hashed_password, firstName, lastName, sex, rating, telephone, role, lastSeen
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have one more question, is it done correctly? Or should i do middleware function in user model, that would hash password? Is it even correct to do functions there?

Comment: both ways work. just make sure your change password function hash password as well.